# Get the click event from a button in a django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

i think the title is pretty clear. I want to know when the user clicks the button to run a piece of code in a function in my views.py. lets say i have this html:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" name="_mail" value="Enviar Mail">  
</div>
```

and i want to run this code if the user clicks on it:

```
send_templated_mail(template_name='receipt',
                    from_email='robot@server.com',
                    recipient_list=[request.user.email],
                    context=extra_context)
```

that´s all i want to do.

**EDIT**: this is the view that i have:

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'
    iva = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21
    total = fact.importe_sin_iva + iva

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente
    extra_context['iva'] = iva
    extra_context['total'] = total


    if  (here i want to catch the click event):
        send_templated_mail(template_name='receipt',
                    from_email='imiguel@exisoft.com.ar',
                    recipient_list =['ignacio.miguel.a@gmail.com'],
                    context=extra_context)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('../facturas')



return render(request,template, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create this function in your `views.py`, map it to the url in your `urls.py` and add event handler using JavaScript (pure JS or using `jQuery` as shown below):

JS (using `jQuery`):

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: your_url,
        method: 'POST', // or another (GET), whatever you need
        data: {
            name: value, // data you need to pass to your function
            click: true
        }
        success: function (data) {        
            // success callback
            // you can process data returned by function from views.py
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="buttonId" name="_mail" value="Enviar Mail">  
</div>
```

Python:

```
def verFactura(request, id_factura):

    ...    

    if request.POST.get('click', False): # check if called by click
        # send mail etc.        

    ...
```

Note that if you're going to use `POST` method you should care about `csrf` (cross-site request forgery) protection as described [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Comment: I just edit the question. Thats the view that i have now, i just want to add in the if statement the click action. Do you say its easier with ajax and jquery?. Thanks

Comment: See updated answer. If you want to perform click action without page reload - ajax is good choice. But I prefer to have different functions in `views.py` to render the page and handle such action as button click

Comment: My english is not so good so let me see if i understand. In the If statement i should put this code "if request.POST.get('click', False): (send email)" and i should use the js code you suggested in the template?

Comment: That is correct. But I propose approach in general, you have to tune this code according to your needs.

Comment: ok! i have never use ajax so one last question: in the "data" field the "name" can be empty? because i´m handling everything with python in the views. Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to pass additional data you should skip this line. Use only `click: True`. P.S. Google some docs about ajax and usage ajax with django. That's pretty simple to use and very useful.