# Django Alert message On Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-templates

I am trying to display a simple alert message once a user clicks the `Save and Email to Corporate` button inside of a modal. The modal submits the form and sends an email based on the auth.users group so the load takes a second. I need to alert the user of this after they submit so they do not continue to click the button. I don't need anything fancy, so I am using `<div onsubmit="myfunction">` and `<script>` to display the alert. This worked the first time but that was it.

How would I code this in the `<div>` and `<script>` to work every time, or is there better solution?

template.html

```
</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div onsubmit="myFunction">
              <input type="submit" form="formset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email to Corporate">
            </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

script

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The email was submitted");
}
</script>
```

Comment: use button onclick instead of div on submit
`<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" form="formset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email to Corporate">`

Comment: @VipulLakhtariya I tried `<button onclick="myFunction"> <input type="submit" form="formset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email to Corporate"></button>` and this just changed the way my button looked but did not show the alert.

Comment: then you can simply put javascript alert on server code where you handle submit..you can show javascript alert there

Comment: @VipulLakhtariya I apologize for not understanding. Do you have an example on how I would do this. Are you suggesting I call from my views.py or some other location?

Comment: you can refere this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854943/get-the-click-event-from-a-button-in-a-django-view)